# Creating a service that allows users to add or remove items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a service that acts as a shopping basket, allowing users to add/remove items. However I am encountering the following error message `Cannot read property 'addServiceItem' of undefined`. Here is my code so far:

**controller.js**

```
$scope.addServiceItem = function(bookingSelected, title, price, length) {
  if (bookingSelected === true) {
    BusinessService.manageServiceItems.addServiceItemcont(title, price, length);
  }
}
```

**services.js**

```
function BusinessService($http) {

  function manageServiceItems() {

    var serviceItem = [];

    function addServiceItem(title, price, length) {
      serviceItem.push({
        title: title,
        price: price,
        length: length
      });
    }

    this.getServiceItem = function() {
      return serviceItem;
    }

}
```

Comment: you probably should return an object, in the service, with properties that you want will be accessible from the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service definition should be returning an object or function. From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services)

> The service factory function generates the single object or function
>   that represents the service to the rest of the application. The object
>   or function returned by the service is injected into any component
>   (controller, service, filter or directive) that specifies a dependency
>   on the service.

```
function BusinessService($http) {
  var BusinessService = this, serviceItem = [];

  BusinessService.manageServiceItems = {
      addServiceItem: function(title, price, length) {
       serviceItem.push({
        title: title,
        price: price,
        length: length
       });
     },
     getServiceItem: function() {
      return serviceItem;
    }
  }
  return BusinessService;
};

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
.factory('BusinessService', BusinessService);
```